# Why does numpy.copy of a numpy.matrix not act like the original matrix? Multiplication with the transpose of that copy does not work

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I need to work with copys of matrices inside functions. But the copy of a
(n x 1) matrix (vector) doesn't behave like it should.

Here I made an example:

Transpose of x multiplied with y gives me a normal vector-multiplication with an outcome of a (1x1)-matrix.

The copys a and b of x and y won't do that. They give back an array with dimension (n x n).
What am I doing wrong here? And how could I avoid that?

```
    >>>import numpy as np

    >>>x=np.matrix('1;2;3')
    >>>y=np.matrix('1;1;-1')

    >>>x.T*y
    matrix([[0]])

    >>>a=np.copy(x)
    >>>b=np.copy(y)

    >>>a.T*b
    array([[ 1,  2,  3],
           [ 1,  2,  3],
           [-1, -2, -3]])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your original arrays are of subclass `matrix`.  The copy is the base `array` class.  Use `x.copy()`, the copy method specific to the matrix class to make another matrix.  Then the matrix multiplication operations will work as before.

```
In [52]: x=np.matrix('1;3;3')
In [53]: x
Out[53]: 
matrix([[1],
        [3],
        [3]])
In [54]: np.copy(x)
Out[54]: 
array([[1],
       [3],
       [3]])
In [55]: x.copy()
Out[55]: 
matrix([[1],
        [3],
        [3]])
```

The solution proposed in the other answer is to replace the `matrix` multiplications with the equivalent ones for `np.array` (`np.dot`).

Answer (score -1):

If you wish to copy a matrix, then instead of using `numpy.copy`, use the `copy` method on `matrix`.

```
>>> x = np.matrix('1;3;3')
>>> x.copy()
matrix([[1],
        [3],
        [3]])
```

Another alternative is to use `numpy.array(x, copy=True, subok=True)`.

Note that `numpy.copy` is simply an alias for `numpy.array(x, copy=True)`, and this causes downcasting of the input.