# Two seemingly equal matrix operations yield different results in Numpy

Tags: numpy

I'm doing the following:

```
import numpy as np
#...
G = np.dot(data.T, data) #data is a numpy matrix
H = np.copy(G)

print "G:"
print G
print "H"
print H
print type(H)

print "Op using G"
print G.dot(v.T) - W.dot(v.dot(V).T) #v, W, and V are ndarrays
print "Op using H"
print H.dot(v.T) - W.dot(v.dot(V).T)
```

The output is the following:

```
G:
[[ 1.21  0.2   0.86  0.7   0.7 ]
[ 0.2   0.07  0.14  0.17  0.08]
[ 0.86  0.14  0.76  0.6   0.76]
[ 0.7   0.17  0.6   0.54  0.55]
[ 0.7   0.08  0.76  0.55  0.89]]
(5, 5)
H:
[[ 1.21  0.2   0.86  0.7   0.7 ]
[ 0.2   0.07  0.14  0.17  0.08]
[ 0.86  0.14  0.76  0.6   0.76]
[ 0.7   0.17  0.6   0.54  0.55]
[ 0.7   0.08  0.76  0.55  0.89]]

Op using G
[[ -1.71e-01  -5.49e-02  -2.78e-17  -4.59e-02   1.34e-01]]
Op using H
[ -1.71e-01  -5.49e-02  -2.78e-17  -4.59e-02   1.34e-01]
```

Why would the result be different if H is an exact copy of G?

Comment: Where did `G` come from?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does numpy.copy of a nympy.matrix not act like the original matrix ? Multiplication with the transpose of that copy does not work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33791386/why-does-numpy-copy-of-a-nympy-matrix-not-act-like-the-original-matrix-multipl)

Comment: @Eric Sorry, made a mistake while adapting the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it while writing the question. Despite their equivalent representation `G` and `H` are of a different type.

```
print type(G)
print type(H)
```

Output:

```
<class 'numpy.matrixlib.defmatrix.matrix'>
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

To me, the fact that numpy.copy always returns an array with the contents of the argument rather than an object of the same class is counterintuitive, though.

Comment: This problem goes away if you use `H = G.copy()`. It's not clear to me whether `np.copy` should behave differently here, and might be worth bringing up on the numpy issue tracker

Comment: See `np.copy`  doc  :  input  `array like`.   output `array`.